# Russian fonts in an English Illustrator CS5

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office, fonts, language, adobe-illustrator

A problem software platform is the following system:

Windows 7 Professional English
MS Office 2010 Eng
Adobe Illustrator CS5

Windows has a rather small set of fonts that come pre-configured out of the box. In MS Office, even if it is a purely English version, I can simply switch to Russian keyboard layout and use any of these bundled fonts.

But when I open Illustrator, an attempt to use one of these pre-configured fonts (except Arial for some reason) results in the actual font of a Russian text not getting changed and stays Arial, which is default.

Do I need to specifically download Russian fonts and embed them into Illustrator? If yes, why do I not need to do this with MS Office products?